# Installed a package called RMariaDB, but I had a problem once a call it in order to used it

Tags: r, mariadb

I need to access a database which is being developed on MariaDB. I've found a package called "RMariaDB" that has a function which allowed me to access the data I need, but once I tried to called the package to use the function I can´t load it.

I tried:

```
install.packages("odbc")
install.packages("RMariaDB")
library(RMariaDB)
```

The error was:

> package or namespace load failed for ‘RMariaDB’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): there is no package called ‘hms’

In order to solve it I tried:

```
install.packages("hms")
install.packages("RMariaDB", repos=c("http://rstudio.org/_packages", "http://cran.rstudio.com"))
```

but it did not work.

Comment: This works for me: `install.packages("RMariaDB", dependencies = T)`. Maybe update R(not sure)?

Comment: Thank you  I took your adviced  and updated R  then I used: install.packages("RMariaDB", dependencies = T) but  still not working. I recieved the same error:  package or namespace load failed for ‘RMariaDB’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): there is no package called ‘hms

Comment: Hard luck! I'd try removing `hms` and reinstalling it. Not sure what the issue is honestly.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error and for me the solution that worked was reinstalling "DBI" library for the latest version (1.1.0)